# Bat file for removing all files in a folder except some files and some extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a bat file for subj.
I have following:

```
for %%v in (*.*) do if not %%v == _clean.bat if not %%v == gc.dll if not %%v == dmc.exe if not %%v == lib.exe if not %%v == libunres.exe if not %%v == link.exe if not %%v == make.exe if not %%v == men.exe if not %%v == sc.exe if not %%v == scppn.exe if not %%v == sc.ini if not %%v == *.cpp if not %%v == *.c del %%v
```

It works almost ok - it keeps files with the names, but it deletes also *.c and *.cpp files, which I do not want to delete.

Solved!

```
@echo off
for %%v in (*.*) do (
if not %%v == _clean.bat if not %%v == gc.dll if not %%v == dmc.exe if not %%v == lib.exe if not %%v == libunres.exe if not %%v == link.exe if not %%v == make.exe if not %%v == men.exe if not %%v == sc.exe if not %%v == scppn.exe if not %%v == sc.ini if not %%~xv == .cpp if not %%~xv == .c del %%v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
for %%v in (*.*) do (
if not %%v == _clean.bat if not %%v == gc.dll if not %%v == dmc.exe if not %%v == lib.exe if not %%v == libunres.exe if not %%v == link.exe if not %%v == make.exe if not %%v == men.exe if not %%v == sc.exe if not %%v == scppn.exe if not %%v == sc.ini if not %%~xv == .cpp if not %%~xv == .c del %%v)
```

For further details, use `help for` to get a complete list of the modifiers - there are quite a few!

Comment: After some trial and errors finally got it right! Thanks man, I didn't know there were so many options for "for" in batch files! If anyone is interested - `@echo off
for %%v in (*.*) do (
if not %%v == _clean.bat if not %%v == gc.dll if not %%v == dmc.exe if not %%v == lib.exe if not %%v == libunres.exe if not %%v == link.exe if not %%v == make.exe if not %%v == men.exe if not %%v == sc.exe if not %%v == scppn.exe if not %%v == sc.ini if not %%~xv == .cpp if not %%~xv == .c del %%v)`

Comment: @revolt Cool, thanks for Feedback.. I fix the problem. Some "Space" was missing. Not it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is simpler and easier to maintain:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "excludeFile= _clean.bat gc.dll dmc.exe lib.exe libunres.exe link.exe make.exe men.exe sc.exe scppn.exe sc.ini "
set "excludeExt= .cpp .c "

for %%v in (*.*) do (
   if "!excludeFile: %%v =!" equ "%excludeFile%" if "!excludeExt: %%~Xv =!" equ "%excludeExt%" del %%v
)
```

Just be sure that the exclude lists begin and end with space.